# Win32 MIDI API endless loop and strange delay needed

Tags: c, winapi, midi

Here is the code of my midi sysex sending/receive function:

```c
void Send_Sysex_Message (int selected_midi_out_device, int selected_midi_in_device, HWND        dialog_handle, std::string input_text, bool record_input)
    {
    int midi_in_result=0;
    int midi_out_result;
    HMIDIOUT midi_out_device;
    MIDIHDR temp_midi_out_message;
    HMIDIIN midi_in_device;
    MIDIHDR temp_midi_in_message;
    char midibuffer[270];
    int limit_receiving=0;

    //set the sysex message
    input_text="F0" + Manufacturer_Id + Convert_IntDecimal_To_HexaDecimalString (atoi(Device_Id.c_str())-1) + Model_Id + Command_Id + input_text + Calculate_CheckSum (input_text) +"F7";
    //Convert Hexa to Ascii
    input_text=Convert_HexaDecimalString_To_AsciiString(input_text);
    //set the temp_midi_out_message structure
    temp_midi_out_message.dwFlags=0;
    temp_midi_out_message.dwBufferLength=input_text.length();
    temp_midi_out_message.dwBytesRecorded=0;
    temp_midi_out_message.lpData=(LPSTR)input_text.c_str();

    if (record_input==1)
    {
        //set the temp_midi_in_message structure
        temp_midi_in_message.dwFlags=0;
        temp_midi_in_message.dwBufferLength=sizeof(midibuffer);
        temp_midi_in_message.lpData=(LPSTR) &midibuffer;

        //Opening Midi In Device
        midi_in_result=midiInOpen (&midi_in_device,selected_midi_in_device,(DWORD_PTR)MidiInProc,0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
        if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        {
           //Get the message error
           midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
           //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
           DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
        }
        else
        {
            //Prepare the midi input buffer
            midi_in_result=midiInPrepareHeader (midi_in_device, &temp_midi_in_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
            //Display error message
            if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                //Get the message error
                midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
                //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
                DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
            }
            //Add the midi input buffer to queue
            midi_in_result=midiInAddBuffer (midi_in_device, &temp_midi_in_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
            //Display error message
            if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                //Get the message error
                midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
                //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
                DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
            }
            //Start Midi In Recording
            midi_in_result=midiInStart(midi_in_device);
            //Display error message
            if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                //Get the message error
                midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
                //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
                DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
            }
        }

    }
    //Open Midi Out Device
    midi_out_result=midiOutOpen (&midi_out_device,selected_midi_out_device,0,0,CALLBACK_NULL);
    if (midi_out_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        //Get the message error
        midiOutGetErrorText(midi_out_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
        //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
        DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIOUTFUNCTION);
    }
    //Prepare the midi output buffer
    midi_out_result=midiOutPrepareHeader (midi_out_device, &temp_midi_out_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
    //Display error message
    if (midi_out_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        //Get the message error
        midiOutGetErrorText(midi_out_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
        //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
        DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIOUTFUNCTION);
    }
    //Send the midi output buffer
    midi_out_result=midiOutLongMsg(midi_out_device,&temp_midi_out_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
    //Display error message
    if (midi_out_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        //Get the message error
        midiOutGetErrorText(midi_out_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
        //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
        DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIOUTFUNCTION);
    }
    //Sleep for the command to be processed ???
    Sleep(20);
    //Wait for the buffer to be recorded
    while (midiOutUnprepareHeader (midi_out_device, &temp_midi_out_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR))==MIDIERR_STILLPLAYING)
    {
        Sleep(100);
    }
    //Clear the buffer from temp_midi_out_message structure
    midi_out_result=midiOutUnprepareHeader (midi_out_device, &temp_midi_out_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
    //Display error message
    if (midi_out_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        //Get the message error
        midiOutGetErrorText(midi_out_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
        //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
        DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIOUTFUNCTION);
    }
    //Closing the actual opened midi Out device
    midi_out_result=midiOutClose(midi_out_device);
    if (midi_out_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        //Get the message error
        midiOutGetErrorText(midi_out_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
        //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
        DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIOUTFUNCTION);
    }

    if (record_input==1)
    {
        if (midi_in_result==0)
        {
            //Wait for the buffer to be recorded
            while (midiInUnprepareHeader (midi_in_device, &temp_midi_in_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR))==MIDIERR_STILLPLAYING )//&& limit_receiving<=10)
            {
                Sleep(100);
                //limit_receiving=limit_receiving+1;
            }
            //Stop Midi In Recording
            midi_in_result=midiInStop(midi_in_device);
            //Display error message
            if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                //Get the message error
                midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
                //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
                DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
            }
            //Clear the buffer from temp_midi_in_message structure
            midi_in_result=midiInUnprepareHeader (midi_in_device, &temp_midi_in_message, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
            //Display error message
            if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                //Get the message error
                midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
                //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
                DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
            }
            //Closing the actual opened midi in device
            midi_in_result=midiInClose(midi_in_device);
            //Display error message
            if (midi_in_result!=MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                //Get the message error
                midiInGetErrorText(midi_in_result, FileNameBuffer, sizeof(FileNameBuffer));
                //Display the dialog box Common_Message_Dialog
                DialogBoxParam((HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(dialog_handle, GWL_HINSTANCE),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_COMMONMESSAGEDIALOG) ,dialog_handle , Common_Message_Dialog_Procedure,MIDIINFUNCTION);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I have two main issue:

- After the midi out message even if i test the still playing status of midiOutUnprepareHeader next i need to add 5 to 25ms of sleeping time depending the lenght of the sysex?
- If no midi input i endlessly stay in the midiInUnprepareHeader while loop ?

Thanks in advance,
Have a good day,
Rgds,

for midi in while loop i added a max loop variable but i got the same error on midiinclose.

Comment: First, I suggest you refactor your code to separate input from output, and concentrate first on writing a function to send the sysex message and wait for it to be processed. It may be necessary to pump windows messages while waiting. 
You may consider using the [newer MIDI APs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.midi?view=winrt-22000) which are much easier to use.

Comment: You could try to use `CALLBACK_EVENT`. You allocate some Event with `CreateEvent()`, and Windows uses this to signal your app. (The app can wait on that Event signal, for example with WaitForSingleObject).

Comment: Refactoring is not possible as midi in is linked to midi out. Putting the ful midi in block after or before the full midiout block won't work!

Comment: You can factor them out, then call them in the order required. In any case, your computer is faster than your midi device, so after sending a sysex, time will need to pass before you can get the device's response, and that is the wait time you've discovered.

Comment: Regarding the delay i know about this fact but i would it to be variable(dynamic) as close as time needed, because this way it s too slow for small sysex and don't know if result would be the same on faster cpu!

Comment: Regarding the refactoring you need the add in buffer before the midi out, so it's impossible to do all from midi in open to close in one block as midireset or midiunprepare buffer would remove it from queue!